# File.Exists detection issue

Tags: c#, .net

i have a bizzare issue with a program ive written where the command File.Exists() doesnt allways detect the same file in the same directory as the executable.

i have somthing like:

```
    if (File.Exists("TextFile1.txt"))
        {
        //do some stuff
        }
```

but the odd thing is if i run this executable in the cmd prompt it doesnt detect the file. BUT if i start this executable via another process it will detect the File Fine.

Any ideas on this bizzare issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you fully-qualify the path?

Comment: Where is the file in relation to the execute?  What about the other process?

Comment: I guess it all depends on what the app thinks the current working folder is...

Comment: It's possible that the two processes have different permission levels, one of which can access the folder and the other cannot.

Comment: I agree with @JustinSatyr. This happened to me in the past when my service did not have permissions to even read the file.  Indeed, according to the File.Exists MSDN documentation, **the Exists method will return false when the caller does not have permission to read the file**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a relative path I have a hunch that the location of the executing assembly is not what you think it is.

In your code try checking where the exe was launched from with:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

Answer (score 13):

This is a relative file path to the working directory of the executable. When you run the application from the command prompt the working directory is set to the directory where the executable is located. When you run this executable via another process (Process.Start), the working directory is the working directory of the host process. You can either modify the working directory before running the process or work with absolute file paths.

Another thing to bear in mind is that the [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) might return false if the account you are running your code under doesn't have sufficient permissions to the folder.

> true if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the
>   name of an existing file; otherwise, false. This method also returns
>   false if path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If
>   the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified
>   file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless
>   of the existence of path.

Comment: Not necessarily, the working directory could be set otherwise.

Comment: The user probably runs the executable using a path, if he doesn't change the directory to where the executable is located, then he will get the problem he is describing. Also, **the OP should use** `Application.ExecutablePath` **as a constant for referring to paths**.

Comment: the file to be read is in the same directory as the executable but when i start the executable from another process (e.g. a process manager) it will work. Starting the executable on its own in the cmd prompt it doesnt detect it.

Comment: @Gelion, that's weird. If `TextFile1.txt` is in the same directory as `Foo.exe` containing the code you have shown in your question and you navigate to the folder containing this executable using a command prompt and run Foo.exe it should successfully find the file.

Answer (score 3):

The file path is relative to the [CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) not where the executable is located. You should fully qualify the file path, or get the location of the executable.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx):

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path
>   information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to
>   the current working directory. To obtain the current working
>   directory, see GetCurrentDirectory.

And when you look at [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx):

> The current directory is distinct from the original directory, which
>   is the one from which the process was started.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that the [CurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) varies between processes.

*However*, an alternative issue could be that each process runs as a different user/permissions and the command prompt doesn't have access to the folder in which the file resides.