# File.WriteAllLines Silent Failure

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I've stumbled upon a somewhat unusual issue with `File.WriteAllLines`.

I have code that looks like this

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename, data);
bool exists = File.Exists(filename);
```

The problem is that **sometimes** file writing fails, but does not raise an exception, and the code thinks the file exists when it doesn't.

- The file is in a network location.
- The file name is `Database.lock`. Does a `lock` extension mean anything to the OS?
- `Exists` returns true, but the file is simply not there. No exception is raised.
- Calling `Exists` from a separate process returns false.
- Calling `Process.Start(filename)` results in an error (not a code exception, just the OS saying it can't find the file).
- The local machine is running Windows 7.
- The remote machine is running Windows XP.

How can I debug what's going on here?

### Update

Following David's advice, I watched the process using procmon.exe.

This is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1mQZ.png

You'll notice there's a lot of things going on repetitively, which I don't fully understand, and at the end, the file is reported to have been written successfully.

### Solved

Thanks to Patrick's suggestion, I discovered that due to a code path I hadn't taken into consideration, the file was getting immediately deleted in a different segment of code. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. I am relieved though that it's just me being thoughtless, instead of unforeseeable network issues.

Comment: What is the datatype of `data`?

Comment: @Steve: a `string[]`.

Comment: The "Process Monitor" tool might help.  It will show you when a program tries to open, write to, and close a file.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: shouldn't you check for this line first then `bool exists = File.Exists(filename);` perhaps create a `FileStream` Object first?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a while for the file to actually get written too, so it could be a timing thing. You almost certainly need to wait til you've closed the file when you write

Comment: @DJKRAZE No, the second line is only there to check if the code thinks it's written the file successfully.

Comment: @DJKRAZE `WriteAllLines` creates the file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @doctorlove The file is not written to the folder even after a long time. Also, `WriteAllLines` should not return until it has finished.

Comment: @DJ KRAZE It looks like he wants to see whether the write succeeded, not whether there's already a file at the location.

Comment: My guess is that the source of the issue here is that the file is in a network location.  Maybe the OS is caching file creation.  Is the file existence short-lived?  Can you post details about the lifecycle of the file and details about this network location?

Comment: I was thinking something more of the lines of this `FileStream SourceFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)` that's why I asked I am familiar with WriteAllLines but since he's doing it across the network vs local this is why I questioned

Comment: @PatrickV The file is not really short lived, the network location is on the local LAN. I'm not sure what other details I can provide.

Comment: @Dave: It's just an array of 3 valid strings, it is definitely not the problem.

Comment: I agree that the problem is most likely the network location. There are some weird issues with caching of files which I ran into in such situations. Please check the logs of the machines to see if there were problems while writing the file (read problems with the network).

Comment: @Rotem Details would be things like the OS of the local system, remote system, and any related things (like is this in an offline files-enabled location).  Given the complexity here, seeing more of your real code including your other-process-test code might help as well.

Comment: @PatrickV I'll try to answer as best as I can: The local system is Windows7, the remote system is Windows XP. As far as I can tell this is not an offline files-enabled location. The 'other process' was just  me opening LINQpad and calling `File.Exists` on the path. My real code is big, but I can't see anything which I can suspect to impact this operation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099200/file-exists-detection-issue.

Comment: @PatrickV The filename is absolute, not relative. I'm trying to debug with procmon as David suggested and will update soon.

Comment: Updated question with procmon screenshot, which I do not really understand.

Comment: If you have `string foo = File.ReadAllText(fileName);` what you get?

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's a great question. Unfortunately now I can't seem to recreate the situation. I'll let you know if I do.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a permissions issue.  File.Exists will return false if you don't have read permissions for the file.  It could be that you are maybe running your code to create the file from Visual Studio and it has admin privileges while you are running LINQPad with other permissions that don't have read access to that location.

Comment: The file is not getting created. I don't see it in windows explorer, and even my process can't run it.

Comment: Maybe it is getting created then deleted.  Could you use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Comment: You might be on to something there, let me check.

Comment: Bingo! Due to a code path I hadn't considered, the file was getting deleted in a different segment of my code.